# How can I make a div reshaped when clicked?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, web

The property I want to implement is like the one Facebook's user posts have. When they are clicked they get bigger and the screen gets darker a bit.

I am open to any critic and help. Thank you!

Comment: Do you have any code you have tried to write? It'll be easier to help you if we can see that.

Comment: have you tried anything and where did you fail ?    Any code showing your issue ?

Comment: It's called popup, and usually there is no div reshaped, but a separate div is shown that was hidden before. [Example of a popup with HTML and CSS](http://codepen.io/imprakash/pen/GgNMXO).

Comment: You need a _modal_ here, you could make it bigger using CSS transforms, but cannot make rest of the page darker. There's a lot of modal plugins over there.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a jquery listener to the box for `.on('click'...)` and inside the function add a `$(this).css(width: x px; height: x px)`

This would allow you to fire the event to change the css.

Link to jquery site for CSS changes. 
http://api.jquery.com/css/

For the background you will just need to change the dom css using jquery selectors.

If you want it more like facebook you'll also need to change the div to float to allow it to show up on top of everything.